# Ghidra error when edit main signature function

Tags: c, ghidra, functions

I'm new to ghidra.
I download the easy_reverse from [crackme.one](https://crackmes.one/crackme/5b8a37a433c5d45fc286ad83) and open the executable file in ghidra.

When I'm trying to edit the `main` function signature I get an error: `Can't parse name: argv[]`.
I searched for this error but found nothing on Google/GitHub and I run out of ideas what to do next to solve it. I would appreciate any help!

Here is a screenshot (I use mac):
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I continued to mess with it some more and found a way.
I correct the signature to have a pointer of argv:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

But I don't really know why the pointer works and the standard C signature didn't. Hope for someone to clarify this.

Comment: `char **argv` and `char *argv[]` are the same thing, just as a different notation. The answers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14298957/c-pointer-notation-compared-to-array-notation-when-passing-to-function explain this fairly well.

Seems like Ghidra simply supports only of those, but will properly decompile accesses to `argv` as e.g. `argv[0]` even if the type is `char **`